# Cannot renew DHCPV6 lease in SLES12

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, sles, dhclient

I need to renew the lease of a certain `SLES12` box. The machine is configured to use `IPv6` only and so far I have tried the following:

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151958/how-to-make-dhclient-forget-its-last-dhcp-lease%20here):

```
dhclient6 -r -v eth0 && rm /var/lib/dhcp6/dhclient* ; dhclient6 -v eth0
```

Other attempts:

```
rm /var/lib/wicked/duid.xml /var/lib/wicked/lease-eth0-dhcp-ipv6.xml
rm /run/wicked/leasinfo.eth0.dhcp.ipv6 /run/wicked/state-2.xml
service network restart
```

After the restart in the above all files get restored as if nothing have happened.

If I do `dhclient6 -r -v eth0` and then `dhclient6 -v eth0` the below messages get repeated forever:

```
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 ...
DHCPOFFER from ...
DHCPREQUEST on eth0 ...
DHCPACK from ...
DHCPDECLINE on eth0 ...
```

The settings in `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth0` are:

```
BOOTPROTO='dhcp6'
DHCLIENT6_MODE=managed
DHCPV6C=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
STARTMODE=auto
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=ethernet
```

It is desirable that no additional tools are installed on the machine. Any thoughts?

Comment: what show log from dhcpv6 server ?